# Using wildcards in MS Word to replace special characters and reformat text

Tags: replace, ms-word, find, ms-office, wildcard

I'm trying to work out how to replace the following sentence:

> What’s Viktoria *made / makes / making* in the kitchen at the moment?

with this:

> What’s Viktoria [**made**makes**making] in the kitchen at the moment?

using Find & Replace with wildcards in MS Word.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble working out a way of doing this. I've made various attempts using things like `(*)(\/)(*)(\/)(*)` and `([! ]*\/*\/*[! ])` but I'm getting the entire string before; i.e. it highlights everything, not just `made / makes / making`. I guess there might be an easier way searching for the formatting (as the only part I want to target is in italics), but any way of doing it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance. Hopefully the explanation is clear enough!

Jamie

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're after. With wildcard searching on, for the search pattern use:

```
(<*>) [/] (<*>) [/] (<*>)
```

and for the replace pattern use:

```
[**\1**\2**\3]
```

If you want to remove the italics, choose italics font format for the search pattern and regular font format for the replace text.

Hope that helps.

Comment: unfortunately that has the same problem as before i.e. it finds the whole string before the italics start, not just the section i'm trying to target. thanks though

Comment: It worked for me for the example sentence in your question. Did it not work for you? Do you have other examples to test?

Comment: @jbowman Did you do the steps suggested about setting italics as the font to find and setting to normal as the font to replace?

Comment: @xidgel i copy and pasted your search pattern and it finds: 'What’s Viktoria made / makes / making', but i want it to find only 'made / makes / making'. same for other examples

Comment: @CindyMeister yes, that works, but i can't add the syntax i'd like to it i.e. `[**string**string**string]` because i can't use wildcards in conjunction with itals

Comment: I wonder if our settings in the Search dialog are different. I have "Use Wildcards" checked. Everything else is unchecked.